# Need help for tricky system of trigonometric nonlinear equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, trigonometric-series

This is particularly tricky set of trigonometric nonlinear equations. How do I go about solving it analytically relative to A,B,C and D?

$\sin(x)\sin(y) - \cos(z)\sin(w)\sin(y) - \cos(w)\sin(x)\sin(z) - \cos(x)\cos(y)\sin(w)\sin(z) = A $

$\cos(y)\sin(z) - \sin(w)\sin(x)\sin(z) + \cos(w)\cos(z)\sin(y) + \cos(x)\cos(z)\sin(y) + \cos(w)\cos(x)\cos(y)\sin(z) = B $

$\cos(x)\sin(w) - \sin(w)\sin(y)\sin(z) + \cos(w)\cos(y)\sin(x) + \cos(w)\cos(z)\sin(x) + \cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z)\sin(w) = C $

$\arccos\left\{\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(w)\cos(x) + \cos(y)\cos(z) - \cos(w)\sin(y)\sin(z) - \cos(x)\sin(y)\sin(z) - \cos(y)\sin(w)\sin(x) - \cos(z)\sin(w)\sin(x) + \cos(w)\cos(x)\cos(y)\cos(z) - 1\right)\right\} = D
$

Comment: There's no general solution for these kind of systems. Substitution of one of the equations in the others, and trial and error, is your best guess...

Comment: Would it be easier to solve this iteratively?

Comment: It depends. It's really hard to evaluate these kind of systems on sight.

Comment: Give it to a numerical solver. It's truly hideous.

Comment: Defining $D_{\star}:=2 \cos D$, it happens that you have $$A^2 + B^2 + C^2 + D_{\star}^2 = 4$$ This relation reduces the independence of the equations, so that you effectively only have *three* equations in *four* unknowns. You cannot solve for each of $w$, $x$, $y$, $z$; at best, you can solve for three of them *in terms of* the fourth. Can you indicate which of these would be the best choice for that fourth? ... It would probably be a good idea if you described the problem from which these equations arise. This context may provide insights into the best way to proceed.